# Import inside function returns ZoneAwarePromise

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Import inside function returns ZoneAwarePromise

Below is the code I use

```
page_types = [
  {
    name: 'anime',
    loadComponent: () => import('./anime/anime.component').then(c => c.AnimeComponent)
  }
];

getPageType(name){
  for (var i=0; i < this.page_types.length; i++) {
    if (this.page_types[i].name == name) {
      return this.page_types[i].loadComponent();
    }
  }
}

constructor(
   console.log(this.getPageType('anime'));
){}
```

the response in console

> ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value:
>   Array(0)}

I expected the output to be the component class

Answer (score 1):

`import('./anime/anime.component')` is an asynchronous operation, that's why `loadComponent` function returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), in turn `getPageType(name)` also returns a Promise. so it is expected to have **ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}** in console log.

If you want component class in console log you should handle the returned Promise.

```js
  constructor() { 
    this.getPageType('anime').then(x => {
      console.log(x.name);
    })
  }
```